# add int value of float to increase selecting speed

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a large table with floating numbers, can it help in reading speed if I add a column that represent the int value of each float? maybe if the int value will be an index, then when I need to select all the floats that starts with certain int it will "filter" the values that are surely not necessary?

For example if there are 10,000 numbers, 5000 of which begin with 14: 14.232, 14.666, etc, is there an sql statement that can increase the selecting speed if I add the int value column?

```
  id  |  number   | int_value |
   1  |  11.232   |     11    |
   2  |  30.114   |     30    |
   3  |  14.888   |     14    |
  ..  |    ..     |     ..    |
 3005 |  14.332   |     14    |
```

Comment: Can you first share what is the current query and explain plan ? To have faster queries, a reference is useful ^^ Because the first idea is to compare number as a string with a like clause, but i guess you have already done that.

Comment: This all depends upon how you plan to interrogate the data

Comment: On a sidenote: Do you really store floating point numbers ( `FLOAT`, `REAL`, `DOUBLE`) in your table? These are approximate values. You should use a precise type (`DECIMAL`) to store decimals. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-types.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a non clustered index on number column itself. and when selecting the data from table you can filtered out with like operator. No need of additional column,

Select * from mytable 
where number like '14%'

Comment: The request you suggests is working fine, but i don't if the author of the question already tried it and found it too slow ? 
Having an index can fast things up.
If it's still too slow, a auto generated column with floats as string with an index on it (because mysql doesn't support function based indexes).

Comment: Thanks. MySql not mentioned anywhere. Solution is for SQl Server.

Comment: It's in the tags of the question :)
For sql server if one wants function based index, one can look at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189292%28v%3dsql.105%29) for computed column that would be declared as the float column converted as a string, with an index on it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Do you have performance issues? If not then why worry?

Then: You need to store decimals, but you are sometimes only interested in the integer part. Yes?

So you have one or more queries of the type

```
where number >= 14 and number < 15
```

or

```
where truncate(number, 0) = 14
```

Do you already have indexes on the number? E.g.

```
create index idx on mytable(number);
```

The first mentioned `WHERE` clause would probably benefit from it. The second doesn't, because when you invoke a function on the column, the DBMS doesn't see the relation to the index anymore. This shows it can make a difference how you write the query.

If the first `WHERE` clause is still too slow in spite of the index, you can create a computed column (`ALTER TABLE mytable ADD numint int GENERATED ALWAYS AS truncate(number, 0) STORED`), index that, and access it instead of the number column in your query. But I doubt that would speed things up noticeably.

As to your example:

> if there are 10,000 numbers, 5000 of which begin with 14

This is not called a large table, but a small one. And as you'd want half of the records anyway, the DBMS would simply read all records sequentially and look at the number. It doesn't make a difference whether it looks at an integer or a decimal number. (Well, some nanoseconds maybe, but nothing you would notice.)